# How to remove data disk from blob storage of SQL Server on Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine, vhd

I have created SQL Server 2014 on Windows Server 2012 R2 using image gallery and it has created below vhds files in blob storage

1. OS disk - 127 GB
2. Data disk1 - 1023 GB

[image]

When I log in to VM I can see OS Disk as `C:` drive and some temporary `D:` drive so I could not see data disk, do I need to attach it? And what is use of that?

While I am creating db on SQL Server it stores related files on `C:` drive so if I don't need data disk as I need only 10 GB storage for database so `C:` drive space is enough, how can I delete data disk1 -1023 GB from blob storage to reduce cost?

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the temporary D: drive. It is automatically created when the VM is started. However, you can (with some difficulty) change the drive letter, see below.

If you are concerned about performance, you should put the user databases and log files on data disks and not on the C: drive.

For high-spec VMs (D-series and above), the temporary D: drive is SSD-based and it can be beneficial to put TempDB on it.

See Performance best practices for SQL Server in Azure Virtual Machines: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sql-performance/

Also Use the D drive as a data drive on a Windows VM: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-change-drive-letter/